# Need suggestion on background worker

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, backgroundworker, scheduled-tasks

I want to develope a delivery application(self hosted WCF service ) which allows scheduling of the emails. User will assign a schedule to email and send it. The WCF service should be able to pick the email and send it on its scheduled time.

What approach shall I use here? I am thinking about following alternatives

1. Use background worker thread to perform this task
2. Any third party scheduling service (I yet to investigate on this)

Can anyone suggest me a possible solution for this apart from above mentioned two?

[Edit] : Can I use SQL Agents for this?

Thanks,

Ram

Comment: hmmm, does this mean I'll be getting more 'enlargement' emails? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw the "...apart from above mentioned two..." but I think there is nothing else to achieve this :)
Either build an infinite loop inside of windows service like this:

```
private void DoTheThing()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                TheThing e = new TheThing();
                Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(e.Run));
                t.Start();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException) { }
        catch (Exception ex) { /* Whatever error handling you got */ }
    }
```

... where TheThing has a method Run which does all that you need every 1 second. This looks silly (while(true) - yeah, right) but has been working non-stop since .NET 1.0 on at least 30 servers :) Just make sure you call this DoTheThing method on Start of your windows service in a new thread.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The solution you are suggesting is good however I am looking for an alternative because background thread will be running for the entire lifespan of WCF service. My concern is it should not increase the complexity of the WCF Service or bottlenexk for other processes.

Comment: Looping is fine in principal, every service is a loop under the hood. Two points, why spawn a new thread everysecond, what if the `TheThing()` gets slow? Secondly, and obviously, don't rely on the delay being exactly one second, check the clock to see what time it is, don't count iterations.

Comment: @Jodrell: 1. Thread.Sleep(1000) was just an example for cases where timing is not that important. 2. In my typical projects where a background loop is needed, the tasks don't depend on each other, opening each one in a new thread would be actually preferred for me exactly for the reason you mention - if one task is not finished yet and the other is already due. So, you are absolutely correct - fire them in the same thread if they are dependent on each other or employ a solution that would keep and check the current state of things.

Comment: @Ram: From your post and comment it looks like you are considering a web app as a host for your WCF service. I don't think a web would work for you because IIS recycles idle web apps. You should host your WCF in a Windows service. Hense my code example and comments.

Comment: You are right, do not use an IIS hosted service for scheduling events, app pools get reset unpredictably, bashing to `at` would be better (not best or even good though). I was just trying to warn the casual reader about Thread.Sleep(), I see you have not misused it. Lastly, if `TheThing` was static but slow you could end up with many threads using memory competeting for resources and eventually freezing the service or even the system, despite the code being idependent.

Answer (score 1):

Have your WCF service queue the email requests either to a database table. Then write a Windows service that periodically scans the table, sends the email, and then update the table with the results.

If you're using a SQL Server, you can send emails directly from it and also schedule jobs to send the emails, saving you from having to deploy a Windows service.

Comment: Oy. Don't sue a DB as a queue; use a queue. :) MSMQ will do just fine, and you can have it persist to disk if necessary.

Comment: @Esteban Araya - why not? Using DB as a queue is better in this case as you can guarantee referential integrity, take advantage of SQL and indexes.

Comment: @Alex Aza: Why does a queue need referential integrity? Why does is need indeces? A queue is a queue... and nothing else.

Comment: @Esteban Araya - from practical point of view, this is not just a queue. You have a list of items to process, but each of them is required to be processed on different scheduled. After you processed item you might want to keep history. History might need to reference schedules, emails, users etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your non-functional requirements... :-)

I can imagine that you would want some reliability in this service. The life-time of the WCF service depends on its host. Eg. if this is IIS, the app pool will be recycled after a certain idle time (no requests coming in to IIS). This would plead for a different solution than a background worker. As you suggest, this could be a third party scheduler but there is also scheduler in Windows. (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd363786(WS.10).aspx) With a small console program, you could have the Windows scheduler call your service, or alternatively, send the email itself.

Comment: WCF service doesn't have to be hosted at IIS. In this case it has to be Windows Service.

Comment: true, but that info is missing in the question. In that case a background worker could do the job fine, reliability wise. However, you could still go for an external scheduling engine...

Comment: I thought that this was obvious that it is not IIS. Even if it was IIS, the processing part should be windows service or even scheduled console application.

Comment: I guess that we agree that the question is not exhaustive in requirements and context. All I can do is give some _examples_ and pointers...